# Cache manifest and query strings

Tags: html, caching

I am investigating using a cache manifest. If I have a manifest such as:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
stylesheets/style.css
```

And in the page I have a CSS element referencing `stylesheets/style.css?v=123`.

Will the `style.css` file be retrieved from the cache or remotely?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The URL in the cache manifest and the URL you're calling must match (INCLUDING the query).

In your example:

CACHE MANIFEST stylesheets/style.css

in HTML: stylesheets/style.css?v=123

The browser will ALWAYS try to fetch the CSS file from the server, since only the query-less CSS file is cached locally. Use of stylesheets/style.css in cache is sufficient.

Answer (score 9):

Just an additional note: if you have HTML pages that expects data in query strings, you could store the same data in localStorage and after redirection can get access the same data in the other page from localStorage.

That is how I solved passing data between pages where we cannot use the query string option with offline cache manifest files.

Comment: @Joson how do you do this if the query string will be a unique record ID?

Comment: Why not use hash to hold data passing to next page?

Answer (score -2):

When you don't have any network connection and want to access that page, it will fetch locally.