# Will HTML5 offline storage always treat URLs with different GET parameters as different resources?

Tags: html, offline, application-cache, manifest.cache

If I use HTML5 offline storage to cache a file like so in the manifest:

```
CACHE:
render_image.php
```

then what happens if the page includes code like so?:

```
<img src="render_image.php?look_ma_get_parameter" alt="foo" />
```

My experimenting indicates that offline storage treats `render_image.php` as different from `render_image.php?look_ma_get_parameter`.  This is the behavior I want, so that's good.  But I want to make sure that this is something that I can rely on, and not merely the behavior of the browser I tested.

Can I rely on this behavior?  Is it part of the spec?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [appcache spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/offline.html#application-cache) says:

> One or more resources (including their out-of-band metadata, such as
>   HTTP headers, if any), identified by **URLs**, each falling into one (or
>   more) of the following categories:

and the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) is part of a URL, so we can guess `<img src="render_image.php?look_ma_get_parameter" alt="foo" />` will get resource from server.

I haven't tested this, but I found some thread about this [Cache manifest and query strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5985765/cache-manifest-and-query-strings). I think the writer of this answer already tested about this.